# Insights on the Access Log Format in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina, access-log, ballerina-swan-lake, ballerina-http

I'm currently following the ballerina http access logs feature as documented in https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/http-access-logs and I'm trying to identify the specific log format used in the ballerina http access logs.
Specifically, I am checking whether we can get a request ID from these logs, where the ID is passed through a specific http header.

Answer (score 2):

The access logs in the Ballerina http module have a fixed log format, and it is not possible to overwrite or customize this format directly. However, we can use interceptors to print logs with custom fields. Refer to the following,

1. https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/http-request-interceptor/
2. https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/http-response-interceptor/